# Using 2 variables at the same time

Tags: jquery, variables, selector

How do I go about doing this?

```
$(function() {

   var foo = $('#foo'),
       bar = $('#bar');

    $('body').click(function() {

        $(foo,bar).css({color: 'red'}); 

    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/each/RGZ4Z/ - Only foo becomes red

**Edit**: Can i stress the fact that I'm aware I could easily do:

```
$('#foo,#bar').css({color: 'red'});
```

I'm simply asking about the usage of variables...

Comment: +0.5 for a decent question. +0.5 for an awesome name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably, what you want is this:

```
foo.add(bar).css({color: 'red'});
```

Here's a demo piece of code that shows how this can work: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3Ep6J/.

There are three choices I can think of depending upon what you want:

1. `var items = $('#foo, #bar')`
2. `$('#foo, #bar').css({color: 'red'});`
3. `foo.add(bar).css({color: 'red'});`

And, more detail on each option:

1) You can either just create one jQuery object in the beginning that has both sets of objects in it like this:

```
var objs = $('#foo, #bar');
```

and then later do this:

```
objs.css({color: 'red'});
```

2) Or just do it all at once:

```
$('#foo, #bar').css({color: 'red'});
```

3) Or, if you already have separate jQuery objects for foo and bar, you can add the items from one jQuery object to the other and then carry out your operation:

```
var foo = $('#foo'),
    bar = $('#bar');
```

and then later, do this:

```
foo.add(bar).css({color: 'red'});
```

Note: somewhat counterintuively, option 3) does not modify the `foo` jQuery object, the `add` method returns a new jQuery object with the items from `bar` added to it.

Comment: Added another option at the end if you don't want to disturb the foo and bar objects.

Comment: +1 for .add() I was playing around with (foo,bar).css() however that only applied it to bar not foo. @Brogrammer looks like jfriend00 got it.

Comment: Found a slightly shorter way to do it for option #4 that doesn't involve an initial empty jQuery object (so one less function call).

Comment: @jfriend00, Option 4 is redundant since `.add` **does not** modify the original object. eg: `foo = $('#foo'); bar = $('#bar'); /* foo.length === 1 */ foo.add(bar); /* foo.length === 1, still */`

Comment: @nickf - thanks I just realized that myself (seems a bit counterintuitive).  I will modify my answer.

Comment: @jfriend00, yeah, I've had some really confusing moments because I've made the same mistake (assuming that it *does* modify the variable), but it actually makes sense if you think about it. It's the same as how `foo.children()` doesn't modify `foo`.

Comment: @nickf - except that the name `.add()` really does mislead you.  In most programming contexts, a method named `.add()` modifies the object you called it on.  But, it's jQuery's style to not modify the current object, but to make a new one.  It looks like `.filter()` works the same way as does every other method I could find.  I presume this has something to do with the stack of changes that it maintains so that things like `.andSelf()` can work.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to jfriend00's answer, but I thought I'd chime in to explain *why* yours wasn't working in the first place.

The [jQuery "constructor"](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) has three method signatures (essentially):

1. `$(selector[, context])` for creating a jQuery object out of existing elements
2. `$(html[, ownerDocument])` for creating new elements
3. `$(callback)` as an alias for `$(document).ready(callback)`

You're using the first option, and `selector` is a pre-existing jQuery object (which is fine), however by adding the `bar` argument, that means that it is treating that element as the **context**. Essentially: "give me a result set containing all the elements `foo` *which exist inside* the element `bar`".

Also, if you *know* that you already have a jQuery object in a variable, it's just wasteful to wrap it another call to `$()`.

```
bar = $('#bar');
$(bar).show();  // unnecessary!
bar.show();     // better!
```

To help me remember, I always prefix jQuery variables with $:

```
$bar = $("#bar");
$bar.show(); // less ambiguous! woo!
```